# Keycloak Admin Console - inifinite loop

Tags: docker, symfony, docker-compose, dockerfile, keycloak

I tried everything I could find in other related posts but Keycloak admin console that is running on a local docker image is **not loading**.

There is an infinite spinner with the text: **Loading the Admin UI**

I am guessing somewhere in my `docker-compose.yml` file is an error that I can not find.

If someone had a similar issue, please help me solve it.

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - "./docker-configs/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf"
      - ".:/app:cached"
  php:
    build:
      context: ./docker-configs/php
    volumes:
      - "./docker-configs/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini"
      - ".:/app:cached"
    environment:
      PHP_IDE_CONFIG: "serverName=Docker"

  database:
    image: mysql:8.1.0
    platform: linux/amd64
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: best_db
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    volumes:
      - ./mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql

  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:22.0
    # restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      KC_HTTP_ENABLED: 'true'
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
      KC_DB_URL_HOST: database
      KC_DB_URL_DATABASE: keycloak
      KC_DB_USERNAME: keycloak
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: keycloak
      KC_HOSTNAME: keycloak
      KC_DB_URL_PORT: 3306
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT: 'false'
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_HTTPS: 'false'
      KC_TRANSACTION_XA_ENABLED: 'false'
    command: '-v start-dev --import-realm'
    depends_on:
      - database
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
      - '8443:8443'
```

Answer (score 0):

Keycloak needs to be able to access the database.
This error isn't super obvious because the logs don't give you a lot of information.

However if you adjust to match the user/password you create in the database part of your yaml to the user/password you're using in the keycloak part, you'll be fine.

So it needs to look something like

```yaml
  database:
    image: mysql:8.1.0
    platform: linux/amd64
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: keycloak
      MYSQL_USER: keycloak
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    volumes:
      - ./mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql

  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:22.0
    # restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_LOGLEVEL: DEBUG
      KC_HTTP_ENABLED: 'true'
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
      KC_DB_URL_HOST: database
      KC_DB_URL_DATABASE: keycloak
      KC_DB_USERNAME: keycloak
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: password
      KC_HOSTNAME: keycloak
      KC_DB_URL_PORT: 3306
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT: 'false'
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_HTTPS: 'false'
      KC_TRANSACTION_XA_ENABLED: 'false'
    command: '-v start-dev '
    depends_on:
      - database
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
      - '8443:8443'
```

Comment: Hi @RickRackow, thank you for the replay. After rebuilding my containers, the issue is still there. Maybe it has something to do with other config parameters?

Answer (score 0):

I had to comment - KC_HOSTNAME option out in docker-compose file and it worked after that. (Based on the hint here: https://www.reddit.com/r/homelab/comments/yzn476/keycloak_in_docker_endless_look_at_admin_console/ ) Can't explain WHY...

```
version: '3'
services:
  postgresql:
    image: postgres:16
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=keycloak
      - POSTGRES_DB=keycloak
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=keycloak
    volumes:
      - '/home/ubuntu/docker/keycloak/postgresql_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data'
    networks:
      keycloak:

  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:22.0.3
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    restart: always
    command: start
    depends_on:
      - postgresql
    environment:
      - KC_PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true
      - KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT=false
#      - KC_HOSTNAME=xxxxx:8080
      - KC_PROXY=edge
      - KC_HTTP_ENABLED=true
      - KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_HTTPS=false
      - DB=keycloak
      - DB_URL='jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/postgresql?ssl=allow'
      - DB_USERNAME=keycloak
      - DB_PASSWORD=keycloak
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=password
    networks:
      proxy:
      keycloak:
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.keycloak.entrypoints=http"
      - "traefik.http.routers.keycloak.rule=Host(`xxxxx`)"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.keycloak-https-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.keycloak.middlewares=keycloak-https-redirect"
      - "traefik.http.routers.keycloak-secure.entrypoints=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.keycloak-secure.rule=Host(`xxxxx`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.keycloak-secure.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.keycloak-secure.service=keycloak"
      - "traefik.http.services.keycloak.loadbalancer.server.port=8080"
      - "traefik.docker.network=proxy"

networks:
  proxy:
#    external: true
  keycloak:
```